# Nested Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, javabeans

I'm dealing with a SEVERE exception in Java that looks like this:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'birtReportRenderer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.convergys.raspberry.server.filemgmt.FileWorker.setFileAuditTbl(com.convergys.raspberry.server.database.FileAuditTbl); 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileAuditTbl': Invocation of init method failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; 

nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

All this nested exceptions were in line like this:

```
exception; exception; exception; etc.
```

What is the sequence of events here? Should I look to the last nested exception and deal with the JDBC, should I start with the first exception or should I look someplace else?

Please, let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: Bottom-up for stack trace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start from root cause (*bottom up approach to the stacktrace*) , so the first one to look at,

> nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot
>   load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'

And it caused ,

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection;

And it in-turn caused the other ones and the failure of `bean` creation .So you need to check your `postgresql` driver first.

Also see [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Last one in log is the root cause. You have a problem with postgres driver.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the last nested exception is a good idea. That is the exception that is throwing first. Than read the exceptions to the top.

so this causes the exception:

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read a stack trace bottom-up, the problem is that your JDBC driver could not be loaded, most likely it is not on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

**Java kept its exception in stack**, the main cause of exception present in bottom of stack, so read exception from bottom to top.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the graphical approach